# Can I install `libssl-dev:i386` on x86_64 system without losing important packages?

Tags: apt, 64-bit, package-management, 32-bit, multiarch

On my x86_64 12.10 system, when I try to

```
apt-get install libssl-dev:i386
```

apt wants to remove a bunch of things:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  build-essential dkms g++ g++-multilib gcc gcc-multilib hardening-wrapper nvidia-current
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev:i386 libssl-dev:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
```

Why does this happen?  How can I install `libssl-dev:i386` without losing gcc?

I noticed that `libssl-dev` and `libssl-dev:i386` have no "Multiarch" field reported by `apt-cache show`, which I think means they cannot coexist. ( https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

libssl is not multiarch compatible at the moment.

See: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=689093

Comment: For future readers: This seems to have been fixed in Ubuntu 15.04. `apt-get install libssl-dev:i386` works fine now.

Comment: For readers from even further future: `apt-get install libssl-dev:i386` throws `E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev`, so better make time machine and run back in past.

Comment: If you add the i386 architecture, then the libssl-dev:i386 package becomes available. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0:i386`.

Comment: Cross compiled and built android i386 and arm libs on Ubuntu 16, using these packages and static linking, seems to work ok.

Answer (score 0):

download the debian package from here and install it

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_i386.deb